# unsafe assembly permission was denied on object 'server' database 'master'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, .net-assembly

How do I add permissions for this:

```
unsafe assembly permission was denied on object 'server' database 'master'
```

Comment: This question is one I had. Glad to find the answer below, whether the question was "closed" or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check and confirm that the account you are using to create the assembly is a sysadmin on that particular SQL instance. You must be a sysadmin to install unsafe assemblies per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx)

Comment: Though the MSDN docs suggest you do, you do NOT have to be a sysadmin. The user in question needs the "UNSAFE ASSEMBLY" permission which can be granted to any login (SS login or Windows auth) through SSMS or T-SQL.